# Excel Quirk - Tab stops working when protect another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I just came across a quirk and have no clue why this is happening - I'm using Excel 2010 and have the following situation:

1. I have 2 sheets - An "input" sheet and a "save" sheet
2. Save sheet is protected; input sheet is not
3. I have a VBA Macro that un-protects the save sheet, copies the data across between the 2, then re-protects it
4. When this macro runs, the input sheet (which was never protected) now has the tab key not working (cannot tab between cells).

To replicate this situation easily, I created a new blank workbook and did the following:

1. Password protected `Sheet2` with the password "Test"
2. Put in the following simplistic VBA sub:

   ```
   Sub WeirdQuirk()
       Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="Test"
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
       Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="Test"
   End Sub
   ```

When I'm in `Sheet1` and run this, afterwards the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is no longer working in the sheet.

Any thoughts on why this is happening / how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, I did come up with a fix, but it's not what should be done - Hopefully someone else has a better solution that I'll accept, but I do want to post this in case anyone else gets stuck in this situation...

What I ended up putting in to re-enable the tab key was adding in the line of code:

```
Application.TransitionNavigKeys = False
```

OR:

```
Application.TransitionNavigKeys = True
```

if you want that feature enabled.

Hope it helps other people.

Comment: This works +1; you may also want to use `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`